# In Meteor.js, use multiple MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver with same collection name

Tags: mongodb, meteor

```
MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://#{server.ip}:#{server.port}/#{server.dbName}")
```

If I call multiple remote MongoDB methods and if there are collecitons with the same names, Meteor throws the error something like this, "collectionName/insert is already exist..."

I think Meteor creates each collection's methods internally so that control each collection, but I need to control several MongoDB at a time with some reasons.

How can I avoid this situation?

In addition,
I realize I can use Npm Mongo driver directly like this without any NPM package involving.

```
var MongoClient = MongoInternals.NpmModules.mongodb.module.MongoClient;

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");
  try {
    var collection = db.collection('documents');
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs){
      console.log(err);
      console.log(docs);
    });
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  db.close();
});
```

But this still forces me to control each DB with the Node.js callback style.
Is there any idea to avoid this?

Answer (score 6):

I have been checking this issue, and I found a way to do it.

The solutions that I had seen to connect several databases where:

```
storageServerDriver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://ip:port/dbName")

@Collection = new Mongo.Collection("collection", { _driver: storageServerDriver })
```

But as you mentioned before, with two collections with same name, an error was thrown (internally Meteor identifies the collections by their name, so it tries to override the structure of the collection already created).

Anyway, to fix this, you can use the following hack:

```
storageServerDriver = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://ip:port/dbName")

@CollectionTwo = storageServerDriver.open('collection')
```

Comment: I keep getting Uncaught ReferenceError: MongoInternals is not defined what should I do?

Comment: MongoInternals is kind of default package as I know. You fixed it already yeah? ;) @Orozcorp I've used this approach a lot still-